# Getting - System.InvalidOperationException - The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have recently updated .Net core 1.2 to 6.0.
An started getting error

System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509
Message=The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'XXXX' through the instance method 'GetXType'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance.

I am getting the error at query

```
var query = (from p in xMap
                         join pc in yMap on p.Id equals pc.PhraseId into joined
                         from pc in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             phraseid = p.Id,
                             keyword = p.KeyWord,
                             vId = pc == null ? 0 : pc.ContentId,
                             typeId = pc == null ? 0 : pc.TypeId,
                             vType = pc == null ? "" : GetXType(pc.TypeId)
                         }).ToList();
```

My GetXType method looks like

```
private string GetXType(int vTypeId)
        {
            string vType = string.Empty;

            switch (vTypeId)
            {
                case 1:
                    vType = TypeConstants.G;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    vType = TypeConstants.H;
                    break;
                
            }

            return vType;
        }
```

As per suggestion when I make GetXType method static I started getting query as NULL.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

As per suggestion when I make GetXType method static and also tried Include() instead of joins I started getting query as NULL.

I am using 'query' in below code where its getting NULL "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'"

```
var gList = (from p in query
                                join g in BMap on p.ContentId equals g.Id
                                where p.vType.Equals(TypeConstants.G)
                                select new
                                {
                                    pid = p.pid,
                                    keyword = p.keyword,
                                    ContentId = p.ContentId,
                                    bType = p.bType,
                                    typeId = p.typeId,
                                    label = g.Label
                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: * I started getting query as NULL* - I do not understand this statement, can you elaborate?

Comment: When I made getXType method static, My 'query' variable is being set to null.

Comment: It is not possible. `ToList()` never returns `null`. Or you mean that `vType` always null?

Comment: That's amusing to me as well. That should not be happening

But since we started getting this only after making GetXType method static, we are not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Again it is not possible. Maybe debugger failed or you have not shown important part or some multithreading issue.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv updated the question and code.
Using Query in other code where its getting NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Probably EF Core failed to make correct final projection. You can do the following:

Correct your query to use `pc.TypeId` without null check:

```cs
var query = (
    from p in xMap
    join pc in yMap on p.Id equals pc.PhraseId into joined
    from pc in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        phraseid = p.Id,
        keyword = p.KeyWord,
        vId = pc == null ? 0 : pc.ContentId,
        typeId = pc == null ? 0 : pc.TypeId,
        vType = GetXType((int?)pc.TypeId)
    }).ToList();
```

Make your nethod `GetXType` static and accept nullable `int`.

```cs
private static string GetXType(int? vTypeId)
{
    string vType = string.Empty;

    switch (vTypeId)
    {
        case 1:
            vType = TypeConstants.G;
            break;
        case 2:
            vType = TypeConstants.H;
            break;
        
    }

    return vType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Svyatoslav I have tried your suggestion but still same error.

Comment: `where p.vType.Equals(TypeConstants.G)` - what is it? It is not in original query.

Comment: Yes this 'where p.vType.Equals(TypeConstants.G)'  using in 'gList ' variable to get data from 'query' variable, that is not in original query.

Comment: I have missed point when your query fails.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Svyatoslav Danyliv 
initially variable 'query' giving error 'System.InvalidOperationException' after I make method 'GetXType' static error resolved. 'query' is having list of records. 

But when I am using 'query' variable for getting result in variable 'gList'. Variable 'query' getting NULL and  "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null error.

Comment: It is strange. You have converted query to List, but exception show that you still access to database. Add full call stack to question.